# Auto terminal command on startup/wake up laptop?

Tags: command-line, autostart

Is there a way to autostart terminal when I turn on my laptop with Ubuntu and have it auto run a command?

I am looking for a method to auto run the following code

`onedrive --monitor`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for a method to auto run the following code `onedrive --monitor`

Disclosure: I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

Please refer to the client documentation as to how to run a systemd service:

https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/USAGE.md#running-onedrive-as-a-system-service

Specifically for Ubuntu:

https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/USAGE.md#onedrive-service-running-as-a-non-root-user-via-systemd-all-linux-distributions